# How to use APP_BASE_HREF with @angular/localize

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-localize

I am setting up @angular/localize for my application but I do not understand how to use both APP_BASE_HREF and @angular/localize. I am using this in my **app.module.ts** to set up **APP_BASE_HREF**.

```
  providers: [
{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/database' },  
             ],
```

In my **angular.json**, I have set up the locales like this

```
      "locales": {
      "ar": {
        "translation": "src/assets/locale/messages.ar.xlf",
        "baseHref": "/ar/"
      },
      "cs": {
        "translation": "src/assets/locale/messages.cs.xlf",
        "baseHref": "/cs/"
      },
                 }
```

Now angular sets the route as **www.my-domain/ar** or **www.my-domain/cs** whereas I want it to be **www.my-domain/database/ar**. Is there a way to achieve this?